# IntelliJ expands Emmet expression in html encoded format

Tags: html, intellij-idea, emmet

New user to IntelliJ ultimate 2016. Trying to use simple emmet expression "div.error" in a index.html file.

When I tab out, it expands to below expression with html encoded form instead of usual html.

```
&lt;div class="error"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
<!-- /.error -->
```

I'm not what settings I messed up with. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences | Editor | Emmet | HTML, make sure that 'Escape' filter is not enabled in 'Filters enabled by default'

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the issue. It is also the response given by Jetbrains Support team.